# CSS Overflow scrollbar blocking bottom of image

Tags: css, image

I'm attempting to hide the vertical scrollbar of an image, while providing a horizontal one when necessary. The CSS I'm using is

```
style="overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:hidden;"
```

This is fine but I am running into an issue where the bottom part of the image is blocked by the horizontal scrollbar. Is there a way to add the bar 'beneath' the image?

Thanks

Comment: Which browser are you using? How are you restricting the width of the image? Can you provide the HTML and any related CSS?

Answer (score 1):

You can move your horizontal scrollbar with padding

```
#img_parent {
   overflow-x:auto;
   overflow-y:hidden;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```